# How do I implement this python old style class as a new style class

Tags: python, class

I am trying to implement this in the new style class and failing. In this example I want to create forests with different populations of plants and animals.

```
class forest:
    def __init__(self,p,a):
        self.alive="alive" 
        self.pl = []
        self.ani = []
        for i in range(p):
            self.pl.append(self.Plant())
        for i in range(a):
            self.ani.append(self.Animal())
    class Plant:
        def __init__(self):
            self.synth = "co2"
            self.name = "coconut"
    class Animal:
        def __init__(self):
            self.carb="o2"
            self.name="orangutan"
```

Edit:
As Lazlow requested. 
My problem was that I was confused between nesting and inheritance. 
so in my approaches I was trying to do this

```
class forest(object):
    ....
    ....

    class Plant(forest):
```

instead of using class Plant(object). I was also trying to define functions which should have been in forest class in Plant class. I was trying to use /super/ keyword to achieve things which I should no have. I was then lost in reading about creating descriptors to do what I wanted.  I assumed that all of these attempts would distract from the problem I had. They were instantly cleared after I read the first response.

My thanks to both of you. 
Regards,
abcd

Comment: Where exactly are you failing in your opinion? I do not see any new class inheritance in your code for instance...

Comment: That was an example of the old style code, which I want to convert to new style..

Comment: Ah, so you did not try anything yourself...

Comment: No, I tried many different approaches. I felt completely lost because I was having problems with scope. I had a fixed notion that my solution had to be nested and it was the root of my problems.

Comment: Please explain next time what you have tried, what went wrong, etc...

Comment: Sure!. I wanted to make my problem as simple as possible to understand with this example program.

Comment: People will help more enthusiastically if they see you also put some effort into solving the problem.

Comment: I do not want to create an argument. I agree with you about adding the approaches that have been tried would help in solving the misunderstandings I had. However they might also distract from the real problem at hand. I hope you do not misunderstand clarity with laziness.

Comment: Bogus post with showing no effort being made is not clarity, but discouraging, and also bad reputation for the site. Please check a few other well-detailed and formed questions. It is nice to help those people...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between old-style class declarations and new-style ones is that new-style classes must inherit from `object` (or some other new-style class). So, to make your classes new-style, just put `(object)` after the class name:

```
class forest(object):
    # ...
```

You're also nesting classes, which isn't forbidden in either new or old-style classes, but which is often confusing and unnecessary. Just unindent your `Plant` and `Animal` class declarations and you should be fine. You can make them new-style too, if you want, by inheriting from `object`.

Note that if you're using Python 3, all classes are new-style classes. You don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`, as the compiler will add that for you if you omit it. It's often a good idea to make it explicit, especially if you use both Python 2 and Python 3 at different times.

Comment: Ah thanks. For some reason I wanted them to be nested. I guess it is not a good idea.